# How to disable workspace indicator in Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: workspaces, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I have to turn it off every time I boot my computer and I find it annoying.

I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 and GNOME 3. I tried to disable it at the GNOME Extensions website but it still turns on every time I boot my computer. There's an update for it and when I try to update it, all the icon (on GNOME Extensions) says is "ERROR".

Comment: Try and turn off the extension using `(gnome) Tweak Tool`.

Comment: Did my answer not work?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Yes I'm sorry. I completely forgot to accept it.

Comment: @Amolith: Oh great! That's fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try disabling it in the `gnome-tweak-tool` which can either be launched by executing that in Terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) or by searching for `Tweak Tool` in the dash.

If that still doesn't work then I'm afraid that there is not much you can do other than mark these bugs as also affecting you:

- [LP #1686796](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-shell/+bug/1686796)
- [LP #1687288](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1687288)